# convert a flat json file to tree structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, d3.js, recursion

I am basically trying to convert a flat json file to tree view. Here the parent child relationship required for tree view is mentained by links key using source and target.

Here is the sample raw input:

```
{
  "nodes" : [
    {
      name: "bz_db",
      index: 0
    },
    {
      name: "mysql",
      index: 1
    },
    {
      name: "postgres",
      index: 2
    },
    {
      name: "it-infra",
      index: 3
    },
    {
      name: "user-count",
      index: 4
    }
  ],
  links: [
    {
      source: 0, target: 1
    },
    {
      source: 0, target: 3
    },
    {
      source: 1, target: 3
    },
    {
      source: 3, target: 4
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see the link field maintains this relation ship, and finally I want my data in this format:

```
{
  name: "bz_db",
  children: [
    {
      name: "mysql",
      children: [
        {
          name: "it-infra",
          children: [
            {
              name: "user_count",
              children: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "it-infra",
      children: [{
          name: "user_count",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to solve this, but it worked for 1 level (to show immediate child of a selected root element.

```
var findObjectByKeyValue = function(arrayOfObject, key, value){
                    return _.find(arrayOfObject, function(o){ return o[key] == value})
                }

var rootObject = findObjectByKeyValue(sample_raw_input.nodes, 'name', 'bz_db');
var treeObject = {
                        name: rootObject.name,
                        index: rootObject.index,
                        root: true,
                        children: []
                    };
angular.forEach(dependencyData.links, function(eachLink){
                        if(treeObject.index == eachLink.source){
                            var rawChildObject = findObjectByKeyValue(dependencyData.nodes, 'index', eachLink.target);
                            var childObject = {};
                            childObject.index = rawChildObject.index;
                            childObject.name = rawChildObject.name;
                            childObject.children = [];
                            treeObject.children.push(childObject);
                        }
                    });
```

But the above code returns me only first level of depndencies, but i want hierarchical relationship. 
I know i can use recursion here. But I am not so comfortable with it.

Comment: where does `rawChildObject` come from?

Comment: where is `treeObject.index` defined?

Comment: where is `rootObject` defined?

Comment: I have updated my question with most of the code @raul.vila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on tracking an object reference and do this without any recursion. Using `Object.assign`, map the list of nodes to its children:

```
// Assuming that input is in `input`
const nodes = input.nodes.reduce((a, node) => {
  a[node.index] = { ...node, index: undefined };
  return a;
}, []);

// organize the links by their source
const links = input.links.reduce((a, link) => {
  return a.set((a.get(link.source) || []).concat(nodes[link.target]);
}, new Map());

// Apply side effect of updating node children
nodes.forEach(node => Object.assign(node, {
  children: links.get(node.index),
}));
```

So I'm taking the list of nodes, and assigning to each (to mutate the node itself -- keep in mind this is a side-effect) a new array. Those `children` are all the links that link this node, and we `Array#map` them to convert their `target` ID into the actual node we want.

Comment: Wow.. your solution is such an amazing.

Answer (score 4):

Josh's answer uses a sequence of `map`->`filter`->`map`->`find` calls, each of which iterate thru a collection of data. This loop of loop of loop of loops results in a stunning amount of computational complexity as the number of nodes in your collection increases.

You can dramatically simplify the creation of the tree by using a single `reduce` pass on each `nodes` and `links`. `Map` can also perform look-ups in logarithmic time, compared to Array's `find` which requires linear time (slower). When you consider this operation is called for *each* element of the input, it's clear to see a significant difference in time.

```
const makeTree = (nodes = [], links = []) =>
  links.reduce
    ( (t, l) =>
        t.set ( l.source
              , MutableNode.push ( t.get (l.source)
                                 , t.get (l.target)
                                 )
              )
    , nodes.reduce
        ( (t, n) => t.set (n.index, MutableNode (n.name))
        , new Map
        )
    )
    .get (0)
```

Lastly, we provide the `MutableNode` interface we relied upon

```
const MutableNode = (name, children = []) =>
  ({ name, children })

MutableNode.push = (node, child) =>
  (node.children.push (child), node)
```

Below is a full program demonstration. `JSON.stringify` is used only to display the result

```js
const MutableNode = (name, children = []) =>
  ({ name, children })
  
MutableNode.push = (node, child) =>
  (node.children.push (child), node)

const makeTree = (nodes = [], links = []) =>
  links.reduce
    ( (t, l) =>
        t.set ( l.source
              , MutableNode.push ( t.get (l.source)
                                 , t.get (l.target)
                                 )
              )
    , nodes.reduce
        ( (t, n) => t.set (n.index, MutableNode (n.name))
        , new Map
        )
    )
    .get (0)
    
const data =
  { nodes:
      [ { name: "bz_db", index: 0 }
      , { name: "mysql", index: 1 }
      , { name: "postgres", index: 2 }
      , { name: "it-infra", index: 3 }
      , { name: "user-count", index: 4 }
      ]
  , links: 
      [ { source: 0, target: 1 }
      , { source: 0, target: 3 }
      , { source: 1, target: 3 }
      , { source: 3, target: 4 }
      ]
  }

const tree = 
  makeTree (data.nodes, data.links)

console.log (JSON.stringify (tree, null, 2))
```

Comment: I agree.. this solution seems better.

Comment: Fair points - the question wasn't getting tons of attention and I was pushing something out fast. My same approach is workable without the same complexity if you simply flatten out the links and nodes first into an array (having objects with an integer `index` is silly) and a Map first (though an Object could also be fine). I've updated it so others don't get hammered if they copypasta me and their app scales.

Comment: Your new answer performs two folds (reductions) very similar to mine, but then you do another `map`->`map` pass (exponential complexity) which is unnecessary. It's an improvement, but I don't believe anyone would write this program if they could see how much added work is being done. When you can visualize process, you can begin to refine your programs to spawn less complex processes.

Comment: What second map->map? It's all linear. Build an array of indexed nodes, map the links to those nodes, then assign the children. No exponentials.

Comment: @Josh I hadn't noticed your answer was edited again before making my comment. I was referring to [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49845859/3).

Answer (score 1):

just share sample, a little different from yours. 
But it give you a hint with recursive function.

[jsFiddle flat array json transform to recursive tree json](https://jsfiddle.net/hoogw/gqa21zp8/2/)

```
            function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
            var out = []
            for(var i in arr) {
                if(arr[i].parent == parent) {
                    var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id)

                    if(children.length) {
                        arr[i].children = children
                    }
                    out.push(arr[i])
                }
            }
            return out
        }


        var flat = [
            {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
            {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
            {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1},
            {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3},
            {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
            {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
            {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3},
            {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2}
        ]


        var nested = getNestedChildren(flat, 0)

        console.log(nested)
```